# Responsive File Manager is proccessing all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-filemanager

I have problem with Responsive File Manager, on my PC is everything working, but client see "Processing..." all the time, like on this image:

[image: this is what my client see]

There is no errors, what can I do? On my PC it's working on every browser.

I'm only using `<a href="javascript:open_popup('/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&popup=1&field_id=photoInput">`  to open filemanager.

Comment: can you share the piece of code you are using so that we can try and provide feedback.

Comment: I was editing the text, there is no other code.

Answer (score 2):

in dailog.php, find

"//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"

replace with

"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.18.0/load-image.all.min.js"

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer, there was too low value set in php.ini for max_file_uploads